# javascript jquery errors unable to resolve

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been getting some errors with my javascrript and i can't figure out
what is wrong. I just made a simple jQuery statement to check if an email field
had a default value and if so, clear the field

Here is the jsFiddle link to the code i am working with: http://jsfiddle.net/qLfBH/
I can't figure out why the jslint is complaining about the line 5 "missing semicolon" and such.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var email_default = "Enter your email address...";

    $(':input').filter('[type="email"]').attr('val', email_default).focus({
    if ($(this).val() == email_default) ;{
        $(this).attr('val', ' ');
    }
    });
});
```

I have also tried using firebug to debug, but the javascript would not show in the scripts panel- probably because of some syntax error. Any help would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I edited the code but its still complaining about a "missing semicolon" (see link to fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qLfBH/3/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var email_default = "Enter your email address...";

$(':input').filter('[type="email"]').attr('value', email_default).focus({
    if ($(this).val() == email_default) {
        $(this).attr('val', ' ');
    }

});
});
```

**FIXED**

Ok thanks for the help everyone. I forgot the "function" under the focus. I corrected the errors below and its working :)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var email_default = "Enter your email address...";

$(':input').filter('[type="email"]').attr('value', email_default).focus(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == email_default) {
        $(this).attr('val', ' ');
    }
});
});
```

Comment: You will need to pass your focus() method a function that it will call.  focus(function() { // place your if statement inside

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
  var email_default = "Enter your email address...";

  $('input').filter('[type=email]').val(email_default).focus(function() { 
        if ($(this).val() == email_default) {
            $(this).val('');
    }
    });
});

Comment: An aside, but Might I suggest [jsHint](http://www.jshint.com/)? It will make you cry almost as much as jsLint, but handles things in a more "progressive" way (options for node.js / jQuery). Plus it's it's easily available on the command line [NPM - Jshint](https://npmjs.org/package/jshint)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues. Here's a cleaned up version:

```
var email_default = "Enter your email address...";
$(':input[type="email"]').val(email_default).on('focus', function () {
    if ($(this).val() == email_default) {
        $(this).val(' ');
    }
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/qLfBH/5/)**

Note, you could also forgo the jQuery and use HTML5's placeholder attribute with just:

```
<input type="email" placeholder="Enter your email address...">
```

Comment: Nice, but why do you use .prop() instead of .val()? Also, I don't get why $(':input') is even working. I would guess $('input') is the correct syntax.

Comment: @PeterHerdenborg - why? because I missed converting that one. Updated. And `:input` in jQuery's input selector. See http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/

Answer (score 1):

Remove the semi colon after you if statement

FROM

```
if ($(this).val() == email_default) ;{ // <----SHOULDNT BE THERE
    $(this).attr('val', ' ');
}
```

TO

```
if ($(this).val() == email_default) {
    $(this).attr('val', ' ');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See updated :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var email_default = "Enter your email address...";

  $('input[type="email"]').val(email_default).focus(function () {  //<-- add function()
    if ($(this).val() == email_default) {   //<-- removed semicolon here
        $(this).val(' ');                   //<-- either .attr('value',' ') or .val(' ')
    }
  });
});
```

**[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/JA7Cj/)**

Comment: Thank you. It fixed my error. I can't believe i forgot the "function()". :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace your JavaScript code with this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var email_default = "Enter your email address...";

  $('input').filter('[type=email]').val(email_default).focus(function() { 
        if ($(this).val() == email_default) {
            $(this).val('');
    }
    });
});
```